# spring boot hibernate sqlite3 missing column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, sqlite

[image: Database table]

Here is database table 
And here is hibernate entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Timetable", schema = "main")
public class Timetable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer Id;

@Column(name = "TimeEnter")
private Time TimeEnter;

@Column(name = "TimeOut")
private Time TimeOut;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "weekday_id")
private Weekday weekday;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employee;


public Integer getId() {
    return Id;
}

public Time getTimeEnter() {
    return TimeEnter;
}

public Time getTimeOut() {
    return TimeOut;
}

public Weekday getWeekday() {
    return weekday;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
}
```

When I try to get all rows from the table I get this:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (no such column: timetable0_.time_enter)

What is this? I can't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error, the columnname has underscore (`time_enter`), whereas in your database/entity (`TimeEnter`) there is no column defined with underscore.The reason for the insertion of underscores is probably because you're using an [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html). It's set on your [Configuration](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setNamingStrategy(org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy)) object or in your application.properties file. See [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19838.html) for an example... You have to fix either columns in database or the namingstrategy in your code to make both in sync.

If you don't want the underscores you can just not set the naming strategy, or set it to the DefaultNamingStrategy you discovered earlier.

Comment: Thanks, when I named columns with underscore it's finally working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not able to leave comments. 
Have you tried put `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in `application.properties`